# Objeto carrega em alguns celulares e em outros não carrega

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde, meu site está com o objeto abaixo na linha 12965:

```
  <script>
  var _cFieldFrame = document.getElementById("customFieldFrame_67");
  _cFieldFrame.src = "//widgets.jotform.io/imagePicker/?qid=67&ref=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host);
  _cFieldFrame.addClassName("custom-field-frame-rendered");
            </script>
```

Porém este objeto carrega em alguns celulares, e em outros não carrega, podem me ajudar?

**Na imagem abaixo mostra o print de um celular que carregou a imagem adequadamente**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Na imagem abaixo mostra o print de um celular que não carregou o objeto**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

A função `addClassName` não existe nativamente em JavaScript, em DOM você tem que setar a propriedade `.className`.

Acredito que o que deseja seria algo como:

```
<script>
var _cFieldFrame = document.getElementById("customFieldFrame_67");

_cFieldFrame.src = "//widgets.jotform.io/imagePicker/?qid=67&ref=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host);
_cFieldFrame.className += " custom-field-frame-rendered";
</script>
```